# how to read with Jquery and element readonly for django

Tags: python, jquery, django, readonly

[image]

see the image plx

there are some readonly field that i set up on django, but i want to read the values using Jquery but really idk how to do it, i want to do it cuz depending of the value that is set on field "tipo" i want a make some values visibles or not.

```
let tipo_persona_check = function(){
    if ($('#id_tipo').val() == 'fisica'){
        $('.field-empresa').hide();
        $('label[for=id_persona').text('Suscriptor');
    }else{
        $('label[for=id_persona').text('Apoderado');
        $('.field-empresa').show();
    }
```

in this case im hidding or showing field empresa depending of the value of id_tipo, but when it is on readonly, this id not exist, there is just a span class called readonly (for all readonly) with the value, but idk how to get from it, i need to know if the value is "fisica" or another from the readonly field tipo, to do things.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did not check whether the `ID` is really visible when this is the case
We assume that the ID is not seen.

The solution is that you can add an `input` in that section so that you can find the ID from it.

> ##### admin.py

```
@admin.register(SomeModel)
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def id_field(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(f"<input type='hidden' id='ID' value='{obj.pk}'>")
    readonly_fields = ["id_field"]
```

and in you js file:

```
id = document.getElementById('ID').value
```